# Resize masonry on orientation change or window resize

Tags: reactjs, masonry

I use masonry.desandro to create a masonry layout for my website. The layout works fine, but after a window resize it doesn't update the width (until I reload the site with F5). 
How can I resize the container of my masonry layout, after a orientation change or a window resize (without refreshing with F5)?

Initialize masonry layout:

```
initMasonry() {
        this.masonry = new Masonry('.additive-post-container', {
          itemSelector: '.item',
          columnWidth: '.item',
          fitWidth: true,
          gutter: 20,
          transitionDuration: 0,
        });

      }
```

I've added a EventListener to react on a window resize. But the masonry doesn't refresh when I call masonry.layout() inside the function.

```
reloadMasonry(){
  this.masonry.layout();
}


window.addEventListener('resize', this.reloadMasonry.bind(this));
```

Thanks for your help !:)

Comment: the `.layout()` is the correct method, and there is nothing wrong with your event listener. Your problem is elsewhere, we won't be able to help unless you show us some more code. If you want to try and debug yourself, set break points in your file. (did the listener get added? is it firing the layout function? can you step into the layout function? is the console writing any errors? etc)

Comment: When the container size changes, I calculate the .item width and call the reloadMasonry() function. The function reloadMasonry() gets called, but it doesn't change anything.. when I resize the window AND press F5 then the masonry layout has the correct width. I don't understand why it changes the width only if I press F5..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your EventListener doesn't cause DOM rerendering.  Force re-render to our component each time the browser windows change size. Thanks to that you will be bring it back with a new, adjusted size.
Check [this](https://hackernoon.com/do-you-still-register-window-event-listeners-in-each-component-react-in-example-31a4b1f6f1c8), might you'll find it useful